# Grunt clean to delete all folders at the root of a directory

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

```
clean: {
  build: {
    src: ['dist/src/vendors/**/*', '!dist/src/vendors/*']
  }
}
```

these globbing patterns delete all files inside folders in the directory, it does not delete files at the root. However, the problem is that it doesn't delete the folders. The end result is the root has all the files (which is right) but it still has the folders (which are now empty).

What globbing pattern should be used to say "delete the folders, a keep the files at the root"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to set the deletion as this:

```
['dist/src/vendors/*/']
```

This will delete all subfolders, but not the files at the root in `vendors`.

Read more about [globbing patterns](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns)

Hope it helps.